My css style in my pageweb change when I link it in ASP.NET MVC project (change positions.mouse wheel disabled....)
When I launch my project in VS Code, the CSS works properly, but when I link it to my ASP.NET MVC project, it works but not quite well (mouse wheel disabled and problems with backgrounds).
I expect that the view of shared _layout maybe causing this problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
